# Deploying meteor application throws exception: MongoError: Authentication failed

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've added a lot of JavaScript to my website that uses a collection to add items to a list, will only display list items that the user sorts with etc. I also have a accounts system Meteor accounts so that only people with an account can add/delete to the collection.

When I try to deploy it fails to do so, and I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. I assume that MongoError: Authentication failed is the main error message to look at, but I'm really not sure what's wrong.

Here is the log message:

```
"rftqe 2019-06-13 11:13:29-07:00Application process starting, version 25

rftqe 2019-06-13 11:13:4007:00
/app/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:313

rftqe 2019-06-13 11:13:40-07:00 throw(ex);

rftqe 2019-06-13 11:13:40-07:00 ^

rftqe 2019-06-13 11:13:40-07:00

rftqe 2019-06-13 11:13:40-07:00 MongoError: Authentication failed.

rftqe 2019-06-13 11:13:40-07:00 at /app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:581:63

rftqe 2019-06-13 11:13:40-07:00 at authenticateStragglers (/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:504:16)

rftqe 2019-06-13 11:13:40-07:00 at Connection.messageHandler 
(/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:540:5)

rftqe 2019-06-13 11:13:40-07:00 at emitMessageHandler (/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:310:10)

rftqe 2019-06-13 11:13:40-07:00 at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:453:17)

rftqe 2019-06-13 11:13:40-07:00 at emitOne (events.js:116:13)

rftqe 2019-06-13 11:13:40-07:00 at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)

rftqe 2019-06-13 11:13:40-07:00 at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)

rftqe 2019-06-13 11:13:40-07:00 at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)

rftqe 2019-06-13 11:13:40-07:00 at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)

rftqe 2019-06-13 11:13:40-07:00 at TCP.onread (net.js:601:20)

rftqe 2019-06-13 11:13:41-07:00 Application exited with code: 1

rftqe 2019-06-13 11:14:29-07:00 The container has crashed. A new container will be started to replace it."
```

When I look this up I see solutions that typically revolve around MONGO_OPLOG_URL; I don't have a MONGO_OPLOG_URL and I've read that if I have an error without it then that means that something else is wrong, which makes me think it's related to the MONGO_URL.

Here is my settings.json file:

```
{
  "galaxy.meteor.com": { 
     "env": { 
       "ROOT_URL": "http://KevinJosey.meteorapp.com", 
       "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds018238.mlab.com:18238/mywebsite_mongodb"
     } 
   }
}
```

I've never seen something like this when deploying before, (the website was very basic to begin with), so I assume this related to the new changes I'm making to the database.

Please help me understand the log message so I can figure out what's wrong and be able to do so again in the future. Thank you for reading this.

Comment: Can you try reaching out to support@mlab.com? mLab support can help with authentication issues.

Comment: I'll try that out, thank you